# Evaluating Contour Integral of square

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluating $\frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint_C \frac{z^2}{z^2+4} dz$ where $C$ is the square with vertices at $\pm 2$ and $\pm 2 + 4i$

So, I rewrote the contour integral:$\frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint_C \frac{z^2}{(z+2i)(z-2i)} dz$

then used the Cauchy Integral Theorem:
$\frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint_C \frac{z^2}{(z+2i)(z-2i)} dz$ = $\frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint_C \frac{\frac{z^2}{z+2i}}{z-2i} dz$ + $\frac{1}{2i\pi} \oint_C \frac{\frac{z^2}{z-2i}}{z+2i} dz$ and my answer for the two contour integrals is $0$.

Is it done correctly or I did incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done the integration incorrectly; the answer is $i$ (backed up by numerical evaluation using mpmath).

The contour encircles a simple pole of the integrand at $2i$. By Cauchy's integral formula applied to $f(z)=\frac {z^2}{z+2i}$
$$f(2i)=i=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-2i}\,dz=\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{z^2}{z^2+4}\,dz$$

Comment: yes! I did it incorrectly there is only one pole, but I don't understand how you would get $i$ not $\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: @EM4 $\frac1{2\pi i}$ is already in the expression in the question. This is the same normaliser as appears in front of Cauchy's integral formula, so it doesn't appear in the final result.

Comment: you don't multiply $\frac{1}{2i\pi}$ with the result what you get from $\frac{z^2}{z+2i}$.

Comment: @EM4 That's because it's already multiplied in and "lost" to the residue that appears at the pole at $2i$.

Comment: I am still little confused how it is "lost" due to the residue. 

can you show me how you get $f(2i) = i$ , because I did $\frac{1}{2i\pi}$ multiplying with $i$ by commuting $2i$ into $\frac{z^2}{z+2i}$ which gives me different answer than yours.